# Updating UILabel resets my views in xCode iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, ios8, xcode6

Whenever my text changes (UILabel) in my game, it resets my UIImageView of a guy running (man), to the starting position (left of screen).

It almost acts as a View Controller reset in a sense...not sure why. 
All ints and variables update fine with a timer, but as soon as I try to change the actual text, everything resets to the starting position.

Here is my NSTimer to update the labels:

```
-(void)updateLabels{
//update lightning strikes label
strikesLeftDisplay=@"Strikes Left: ";
strikesLeftDisplay=[strikesLeftDisplay stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", strikesLeft]];
lblLeft.text=strikesLeftDisplay;
 }
```

Here is my onDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
currentScreenX=self.view.frame.size.width;
currentScreenY=self.view.frame.size.height;

currentLevel=1;
runningSpeed=7;
lightningSpeed=0.023;
runnerImageNumber=0;
strikesLeft=3;

cloudImage.hidden=YES;
boltImage.hidden=YES;

runningMovement=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(startRunning) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

labelScanner=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabels) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



[super viewDidLoad];

 }
```

and finally, here is my startRunning method:

```
 - (void)startRunning{
if(livesLeft==0){[self endGame];}

manX=man.frame.origin.x;
manY=man.frame.origin.y;

if([direction isEqualToString:@"left"] && touchX < (manX+20)){
    man.center=CGPointMake(man.center.x - runningSpeed,man.center.y);
}else if([direction isEqualToString:@"right"] && touchX > (manX+22)){
    man.center=CGPointMake(man.center.x + runningSpeed,man.center.y);
}
else{
    direction=@"0";
}




//animate runner
if ([direction isEqualToString:@"right"]){
    if(runnerImageNumber==1){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run1.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==2){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run2.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==3){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run3.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==4){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run4.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==5){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run5.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==6){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run6.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==7){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run7.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==8){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run8.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==9){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run9.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    runnerImageNumber++;
    if(runnerImageNumber==9){runnerImageNumber=1;}
}
if ([direction isEqualToString:@"left"]){
    if(runnerImageNumber==1){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run10.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==2){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run11.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==3){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run12.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==4){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run13.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==5){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run14.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==6){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run15.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==7){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run16.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==8){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run17.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    if(runnerImageNumber==9){UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"run18.png"];[man setImage:image];}
    runnerImageNumber++;
    if(runnerImageNumber==9){runnerImageNumber=1;}
}






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you see this type of thing because you're setting the view's frame (or center or bounds.size) directly but your app uses auto layout.

When you change the label's text, the label flags itself as needing layout.  This make auto layout run and set the frames of your views according to the constraints on them, undoing any changes you made directly to the frames of those views.

Instead of setting `man.center` directly, you need to modify the constant of the constraint that controls the X position of the man.  If you created the constraint in a xib or storyboard, you can connect the constraint to an outlet (probably in your view controller) to access it.

You would probably be better off switching to SpriteKit for your game.

Comment: I tried setting (pinning) the constraint for the man via storyboard for both sides, as well as the bottom, but it looks like it's still resetting.

This really seems to be the only hiccup so I'd rather not use a whole new framework just to update a UILabel.

Comment: How are you creating the label: xib, storyboard, or code?

Comment: I created the label in storyboard-

Comment: Edit your post to include the code where you modify the constraint.

Comment: The only code that makes the man run is above, in the startRunning method-

Comment: Then you need to do what I said in my answer: connect an outlet to the constraint that controls the man's X position, and then (in code) modify the constraint's constant to move the man.

Comment: Thank you for the response- I think I am just going to create the UILabel programmatically so It will update. Looks like that works- I appreciate the explanation of why it was acting as it did though.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  Make sure that in the Interface Builder Document the use auto layout checkmark is UNCHECKED! This fixed the problem for me.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You are my savior. Problem still occurs in Xcode 6.1 and this fixed it. I selected my UIView for the entire screen and deselected "Use Auto Layout" and I no longer had problems.